# Android sort ArrayAdapter with exceptions for two rows

Tags: android, string, sorting, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter` with `Objects`. Currently I sorted it with a compare-method. It works fine, but I have to switch to elements of the entries to the first and second row.

Can you help me by finding a good solution for this.

The List consists of Category names. "Last Used" and "favs" should be at the beginning.

Should I look for these entries after sorting, or would you do this at the same moment?

Comment: Look at Collections.sort (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List<T>, java.util.Comparator<? super T>)

Comment: Thanks, i looked after that and tried with String.compareToIgnoreCase()
This works pretty but only for one element. I have to. When i Use this twice, the elements will be placed at the bottom and not above all others.

Comment: You can just test in the compare method if any of the items is 'Last Used' or 'Favs' and then report that item as smaller, whatever the other element is; all other items compare as usual. This will sort the two special items at the beginning of the list.

Comment: If you share your code maybe more people can help you